# UITabBarController Outlet in App Delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c

i want to create an Outlet of UITabBarController in App Delegate File ,so that i can create a property of it .    , but i am not be able to Connect it , can anyone suggest me .
alos i am using storyboards and ARC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this & try again.

```
@interface ClassName : UIViewController<UITabBarControllerDelegate>
```

Comment: yes , but the problem is that i cannot connect the property to UITabBarController  with the Storyboard in Interface Builder .